# Making an alias in cygwin to connect to a directory

Tags: git, bash, cygwin

I want to make a shell alias to connect to a directory I do all of my work in.  I have tried the following in my `.bashrc` file:

```
alias gitImmersion="cd 'c:/java/Git-Immersion/git_tutorial/work'"
```

and

```
alias gitImmersion='cd c:/java/Git-Immersion/git_tutorial/work'
```

In both cases I get a `No such file or directory error`, but when I type the command in by hand it works.  I don't know if it is related but since I have modified my .bashrc file I get several -bash:$'\r': command not found errors when I start cygwin.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Those errors mean you saved the file with DOS line-endings and they *will* confuse bash. Run `dos2unix` on the file and see if that fixes the errors and the alias (in this case both should work but the if the path needed quotes the first one would be necessary).

Comment: The dos2unix fixed the problem.  I tried to save it with Notepad using Ansi encoding but that didn't help.  Is there an editor I can use on Windows which will keep it in unix style or do I just need to run the dos2unix every time I make a change?  Thanks for the help!  By the way I used alias gitImmersion="cd 'c:/java/Git-Immersion/git_tutorial/work'"
 in the .bashrc file.

Comment: This isn't an "encoding" issue. It is a line-endings issue. Any editor that can control line-endings will work. (That rules out notepad and wordpad but just about any other competent editor can do it.)

Comment: So using NotePad+ and saving it as a Unix script file would work?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing it into this format and see if it helps

```
alias gitImmersion="cd /cygdrive/c/java/Git-Immersion/git_tutorial/work"
```